# The default icon(arrow) on jquery UI accordion not appearing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-ui-css-framework

I am using jquery ui accordion just as shown in their demo

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

However the default arrow icons are not appearing. Can anyone please tell what could be the reason. I am using following js and css:

1) jquery.min.js

2) jquery-ui.min.js-1.8.13

3) jquery-ui.css-1.8.15.

Is there anything I am missing out??

Comment: Did you link the css properly on your page?

Answer (score 0):

i did not review your code, so can get understand whats doing wrong with your code.

Just try below link for your task, for me its working nicely;

http://chandreshmaheshwari.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/accordian-menu/

Thanks.